# WPF ListView into Datagrid reading one observable dictionary possible?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I have a problem to understand why I can't connect a listView to a datagrid with the same dictionary to display the items.

The dictionary is:

```
Public Property PersonsInAHouse As New Observable ([...],KeyValuePair(of Persons, HouseAdress))
```

Code:

```
 <Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding PersonsInAHouse.Values}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Expander>
                                <!--ListView with PersonsInAHouse Dictionary-->
                            </Expander>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

How can I implement a ListView to display the items with the same dictionary into the Expander?

Answer (score 0):

You must bind to the `ItemsSource` of the `DataGrid`:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}" />
```

Or the `DataContext` of the `DataGrid`:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.PersonsInAHouse.Values, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}" />
```